# mod_rewrite question - case sensitivity

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a site and am using .htaccess to re-direct url's as follows:

```
http://mysite.com/StoreName/
```

is redirected to

```
http://mysite.com/stores/StoreName/
```

and it is done invisibly to the user so the user still sees

```
http://mysite.com/StoreName/
```

in their browser bar (which is what I want).

So far, so good. The .htaccess code that is doing this for me is

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$ http://mysite.com/stores/$1/ [L]
```

and it works great, with one small exception.

If the actual folder is `/stores/StoreName/` (note the capitalized "S" and "N") and the user types in

```
http://mysite.com/storename/
```

into their browser bar, they still get redirected correctly, but it is no longer invisible. The browser now shows

```
http://mysite.com/stores/StoreName/
```

Is there any way for the `http://mysite.com/storename/` entry to get redirected correctly, and still show `http://mysite.com/StoreName/` in the browser bar? I did try

```
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9_]+)/$ http://mysite.com/stores/$1/ [L,NC]
```

but this led to a 'file not found' error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This rule does not modify the case, and it does not redirect the client. Something else in your configuration is redirecting it, possibly your 404 ErrorDocument.

Comment: Well, the mod_spelling module is correcting for case and the rule is redirecting the client. I just want it to be invisible.

Comment: So http://mysite.com/storename is being redirected by mod_rewrite to http://mysite.com/stores/storename and the mod_spelling module is then correcting it to http://mysite.com/stores/StoreName . That's all good, but I want the browser bar to show http://mysite.com/StoreName

Comment: So then what you're saying is that your problem has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Well, I'm wondering if there is any mod_rewrite voodoo I can use so that at the end of the day, the user can type in a link with incorrect capitalization and still be redirected invisibly. I'd like http://mysite.com/storename to show up as http://mysite.com/StoreName in the browser bar, but still be redirected to http://mysite.com/stores/StoreName invisibly.